# dbt source.yml based on target name

Tags: yaml, dbt

I have 2 env, 'dev' and 'prod'.
In some case, the source will be different between dev and prod. How do we automatically change the source.yml when we run the dbt in prod?

source.yml in **dev**

```
version: 2
sources:
  - name: idn_stg_mti
    description: 'Data ingested from MTI channel'
    database: DEV_IDN
    schema: idn_stg_mti
```

source.yml in **prod**

```
version: 2
sources:
  - name: idn_stg_mti
    description: 'Data ingested from MTI channel'
    database: PRD_IDN
    schema: idn_stg_mti
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little bit of jinja to achieve this. Your exact use case is described in the [dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/target)

```
sources:
  - name: idn_stg_mti 
    database: |
      {%- if  target.name == "dev" -%} DEV_IDN 
      {%- elif target.name == "prod"  -%} PRD_IDN
      {%- else -%} invalid_database
      {%- endif -%}
    schema: idn_stg_mti
```